# C# Exception Parse.Double

Tags: c#, math

I have a simple C# Web console application that utilises the HTML Agility Pack to retrieve data from a given website. My code takes a value from a form field and attempts to reconstruct it into inches, the code works! however I was wondering if there was a more correct, simpler way of achieving my goal?

```
string MetricName = "686 x 1981mm, 35mm Thick: £143.01";

var priceGrab = MetricName.Substring(MetricName.LastIndexOf('£') + 1);
// 25.4 is what we divide the MM value by to get the inch value
const double imp = 25.4;

Match firstMeasurements = Regex.Match(MetricName, @"\d+");
Match secondMeasurements = Regex.Match(MetricName, @"x([^,]*)");
Match thicknessMeasurements = Regex.Match(MetricName, @",([^mm]*)");

string firstM = firstMeasurements.Value;

//Convert MM to Inches
double first = double.Parse(firstM) / imp;

string secondM = secondMeasurements.Value;
Match secondFixed = Regex.Match(secondM, @"\d+");
string secondM1 = secondFixed.Value;

//Convert MM to Inches
double second = double.Parse(secondM1) / imp;

string thicknessM = thicknessMeasurements.Groups[1].Value;
Match thirdFixed = Regex.Match(thicknessM, @"\d+");

//Convert MM to Inches
double three = double.Parse(thicknessM) / imp;

ImperialVariant = string.Format("{0} x {1}\", {2}\" Thick: £{3}",first.ToString("00"), second.ToString("00"), three.ToString("0.00"), priceGrab);

return ImperialVariant;
```

ImperialVariant will then equal to:

> 30 x 78", 1.38" Thick: £143.01

My program raises the following exception for an unknown reason.

> at System.Number.ParseDouble(String value, NumberStyles options, NumberFormatInfo numfmt)
>   at System.Double.Parse(String s)

Is anybody able to provide some feedback on this??

Thank you

Comment: What is the exception exactly?

Comment: which line of code throws the exception. you have 3 places where it could be a possibility. also what are the values you are getting from your Regex match for each of the 3 values?

Comment: I can't help but note that `[^mm]` should be `[^m]`.

Comment: @KendallFrey Could be, not should be. They mean the exact same thing, and `[^mm]` is potentially clearer in documenting what it's supposed to do. (Personally, I wouldn't use either `[^mm]` or `[^m]`, but if I were to use it, I might be tempted to go for `[^mm]` as well.)

Comment: I've tried your example and I didn't get any exception. Can you give us an input string where the Exception is thrown? Anyways try using double.TryParse() instead double.Parse() so you'll never get an exception when the input string isn't in the correct format.

Comment: @hvd It may be clearer in what it's supposed to do, but it's also deceptive in what it does do, because it doesn't in fact look for the string `mm`, but a single `m`. That and it just plain bugs me. :)

Comment: Also, one single regex, describing the whole relevant part, could be better to be read: `(?<first>\d+)\sx\s(?<second>\d+)mm,\s(?<third>\d+)mm\sThick`

Comment: @KendallFrey I know, it looks for any of the characters in "mm", rather than the string "mm". That's why I wouldn't use `[^` in the first place. But I don't think it's any more or less deceptive than `[^m]`: I tend to assume the reader of a regex knows the basics. Perhaps you tend to assume a reader not familiar with regexes, and in that case, I can see your point.

Answer (score 4):

It is a bit confusing as trying to execute your code does not produce any exception. However,

> I was wondering if there was a more correct, simpler way of achieving my goal

I would recommend simplifying the regular expressions, using `Decimal` for floating point numbers, use format specifiers to format the output and make sure that the correct `CultureInfo` is used when parsing and formatting:

```
String ConvertToImperial(String text) {
  var regex = new Regex(@"^(?<first>\d+)\s*x\s*(?<second>\d+)mm,\s*(?<third>\d+)mm Thick: £(?<price>\d+\.\d+)$");
  var match = regex.Match(text);
  if (!match.Success)
    return null;
  var first = Int32.Parse(match.Groups["first"].Value);
  var second = Int32.Parse(match.Groups["second"].Value);
  var third = Int32.Parse(match.Groups["third"].Value);
  var price = Decimal.Parse(match.Groups["price"].Value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
  return String.Format(
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
    @"{0:F0} x {1:F0}"", {2:F2}"" Thick: £{3:N2}",
    ConvertToInches(first),
    ConvertToInches(second),
    ConvertToInches(third),
    price
  );
}

Decimal ConvertToInches(Decimal mm) {
  return mm/25.4M;
}
```

This code can still throw exceptions if some very large numbers are provided in the input string.

Comment: Thank you Martin and everyone, that code works perfect! I apologise for not providing further information originally, I was in a bit' of a rush. Thank you again, very good responses.